# why doesn't marked('#content') render well

Tags: javascript, markdown

Now I have three scripts in my html file. And there aren't any code about marked in mystyle.js.

So the question here is:

output of my html file in localhost

[image]

Another [site](http://markdown-here.com/index.html) render well

[image]

I want to know why would this happened? Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/mystyle.js' %}"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a space between the hash and text. Marked will not render it correctly otherwise.

```
// prints <p>headline</p>
marked('#headline');
// prints <h1>headline</h1>
marked('# headline');
```